# Kafka Connect HDFS Sink with Azure Blob Storage

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, azure-blob-storage, apache-kafka-connect

I want to connect to Azure Blob Storage with Kafka HDFS Sink Connector.
So far I have done:

1. Set `kafka-connect` properties:

   ```
   hdfs.url=wasbs://<my_url>
   hadoop.conf.dir={hadoop_3_home}/etc/hadoop/
   hadoop.home={hadoop_3_home}
   ```
2. And in `core-site.xml` added support for wasbs:

   ```
   <property>
       <name>fs.wasbs.impl</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem</value>
   </property>
   ```
3. Exported `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` variable, added to `PATH`

But anyway, Hadoop can not find the class - `NativeAzureFileSystem`:

```
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.storage.StorageFactory.createStorage(StorageFactory.java:29)
 ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem not found
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
```

Could you please help with this issue. Is it even possible?

Comment: Well, did you add the `hadoop-azure` package to the classpath?

Comment: Also, https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/pull/130

Comment: thanks @cricket_007, but I have seen that pull request.

Comment: And have you tried checking it out, building the JAR, and using it?

Comment: @cricket_007, not yet.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for your time. I added HADOOP_CLASSPATH to the CLASSPATH by hand, now it connects to Blob Storage.

Comment: Would you like to answer your question below so it can help others with this problem?

Comment: @cricket_007, I just haven't reached the finish. Actually my goal is: backup everything from Kafka to Azure BLOB of any data format. As far as I got the point - hdfs sink connector needs predefined data format, for example json/avro. And if the data in kafka is not of that format, it fails. But I have tested with file stream sink connector with the same worker configs, it reads and outputs data as is. Is it possible to do the same with HDFS Sink? A bit newbie in kafka/bigdata, I would appreciate any help

Comment: The HDFS sink only has json, avro, and parquet support, not plain text. If you want to actually backup Kafka message per message, you should setup another cluster in Azure, and use MirrorMaker, or Confluent Replicator. Personally, I don't see how landing data in blob storage is backing it up, if you have no way of reading it back out in the order it's written https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/post-deployment.html#backup-and-restoration

Comment: Do you still need help on this case? 
@cricket_007 Could you please post your comment on the answer section ? 

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my goal is: backup everything from Kafka to Azure BLOB of any data format.

The HDFS and cloud  connectors can't backup "any format". Confluent's Avro is the first class citizen of file formats. JSON secondly, but there is not a "plain text" format, from what I've found. I think the HDFS connector does support "byte array" format.

As I mentioned in the comments, in my opinion, a backup of Kafka is different than indefinitely retaining the data to a file system. Backing up Kafka-to-Kafka includes use of MirrorMaker.

If you want to use any format, Spark, Flink, NiFi, or Streamsets have more flexibility for handling that out of the box